# Eclipse and JAVA EE 7

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, ide

I have downloaded Java EE 7. My question is what plugins should I download to make ECLIPSE working as good as it is possible with JAVA EE 7?

I mean I am new to servlets and JSP I have to be able to create Project that has all required files folders etc (Like when I create ordinary Java project in Eclipse).

I know my question is not to specific but in general:

1. I want to have all my files in one project (Like in ordinary Java project in ECLIPSE)
2. I want deploy it in easy way
3. What plugins I have to install on Eclipse to achieve this?
4. I am using TOMCAT server but when I installed JAVA EE 7 it installed GLASSFISH which one use?

Comment: To start with web project, you need to understand the folder structure of a web application. You can configure Tomcat to your eclipse manually if you dont want to use Glassfish.

Comment: You can't download JEE 7, its a specification. Oracle simply provides a misleadingly named bundle package which is simply Glassfish with a runtime. Glassfish is one implementation of the JEE specification, there are plenty of others. Wikipedia has a nice list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to build Java EE projects is to download new Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers which is available [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr2/)

Eclipse for Java EE Developers is everything what you need for your beginner projects. There is no point to look for anything else for your purposes in my opinion.

You can use tomcat or glassfish for your projects. You can configure it by yourself in Eclipse. 
To do this go to menu bar.

```
Window/Show view/Other/type "server" than press OK
```

New window will show up with link "*No servers  are available. Click this link to create a new server*"

New windows will appear where you can add server of your choice. Personally I prefer Tomcat.

If you have problems with it find beginners movies on youtube where you can easily find how someone else creates java ee projects in eclipse.

Hope that make sense for you.

Comment: I need develop server side code (servlets) and client side code (JSP)
Will that be possible with that IDE to create project that will contain all server side code and client side code?
I mean will it logically connect all of the classes etc so I will have opportunity to test it and make changes without jumping from one project to another?

Comment: I understand what are you talking about. You didn't explain that clearly but I think I understand that. Eclipse for J2EE is the best free tool on the market for the Java EE Projects.That link which I provided is the best for you. It will "magically" connect your classes, has templates for jsp,servlets etc when you create new jsp file but it won't write code for you. There is no IDE which write code for you. It only helps you to automatize your tasks.

Comment: yes, it is possible to do that within one project. You will need WebContent folder within your project, for all your jsp files. Eclipse does it for you, just create new project (File -> New -> Dynamic Web Project) and you're good.
When you add new files to the project this way (File -> New -> Servlet or JSP File) they will also be added automatically to web.xml file so the project is mapped on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the plugins work in Java EE 7. To deploy it you can use an Ant File and can use any server (Tomcat, Glassfish, Jboss...).

Maybe, Git plugin will be useful to save your code in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Not need to any plugin if you download java EE 7 jsp and servlet are standard for javaEE and when you create new jEE project it will contain all your folder as java standard with additional folder as web.xml and web-inf which contain your jsp pages ,you can user Maven to manage your project and i advice tomcat as server with jEE

Comment: Yeah but Im using IBM RSA. So if i dont find any plugins that will make RSA working like Eclipse IDE for Java EE devs I will have to install ECLIPSE